# summary of the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need gridview summary on footer...

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
        decimal totalPrice = 0M;
        int totalItems = 0;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPrice");
            decimal price = Decimal.Parse(lblPrice.Text); 
            totalPrice += price;
            totalItems += 1; 
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblTotalPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice");
            lblTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString(); 
        }
 }
```

But its not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare totalPrice and totalItems as globel variable like this

```
decimal totalPrice = 0M;
int totalItems = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    ...

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method `totalPrice` is declared in method scope, so it will start from zero for every row. When it comes to footer row, it will be again zero. There are at least two options:

1. Include `total = sum(price)` column to your SQL statement and bind
   it to your footer;
2. Move `totalPrice` to private field of the page from your method. In
   this case your code should work